# Add HTTPS support for StackExchange websites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't SO fix the Firesheep style cookie theft?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-so-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft)

Would like to see the StackExchange websites all support HTTPS.