# Automatically logged out

Tags: discussion, bug, login, logout

Contrary to a lot of the questions here on meta, I'm not having trouble logging out, but rather staying logged in.

Before, sessions seemed to last "forever" but in the last few days I've found that every time I open a new tab for any Stack Exchange site, I've been logged out.

I'm on Google Chrome (Developer Build, currently version 26.0.1384.2, but updated very often), Mac OSX Mountain Lion.

Most notably, the problem has been with Stack Overflow as it's the one I use most often. Meta and Area 51 may have had the same problem, but because I use those sites less often, it's not too unusual to find myself logged out.

Is this some setting I've changed or has the login system had a recent revamp? 
Possibly something that's changed in Chrome with regard to storing session information?

Comment: Which browser? Which operating system? Which sites?

Comment: Do you clear your cookies regularly? Do you have a process that does that? AV/Anti Malware?

Comment: No, and no. I've not (consciously) changed any Internet settings. Possibly something that's changed in Chrome with regard to storing session information?

Comment: It's possible. We have not changed session handling/login recently, which is why I suspect changes on your end.

Comment: I'll try a stable build of Chrome.

Comment: Beta and developer versions of browsers aren't supported.

Comment: Let me guess: you're using Google as the OpenID provider right? I suspect they are to blame, as I suffer the same issue on YouTube (used to be always logged in and suddenly noticed I get logged out in the recent days without reason), though Gmail appears to work fine.

Comment: Having the same issue since a couple days ago. Using Blogger's OpenID and Opera 12.14 on Win7.

Comment: I get the same issue on all SE sites starting some time late last week; logins barely last a day.  I alternate between Safari 5.1.7 and a non-dev version of Chrome, which was not a problem previously.  Google is my OpenID provider.

Comment: How can I find out who is my OpenID provider?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Since a couple of days I have to relogin on every visit. I use the latest Firefox browser. No caches cleared. No AV installed (besides MS Security Essentials). I'm using MyOpenID.

Comment: Same problem here, I'm using Chrome (regular upgrade mode v24) and Google user id. After attempting to login it sometimes succeeds and sometimes gives an [authentication error](http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/authenticate)

Comment: Same problem here.  Happening in all browsers.  Started during the Feb 9 move to New York.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166874/getting-logged-out-multiple-times-issue-continues

Comment: I don't know what can be done to get somebody to take this seriously, but I updated my own thread with more details.  Maybe eventually it will get fixed.... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166874/getting-logged-out-multiple-times-issue-continues

Comment: **Good news!**  This was confirmed as a real bug and fixed yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169560/157574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Good news!**  This was confirmed as a real bug and fixed yesterday:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169560/157574

**Quote Jarrod Dixon**:

> We refresh your authentication cookie pretty aggressively to help
>   deter theft - this refresh can happen on any url that needs to know
>   who you are.
>
> I introduced a bug that would access a user's cookie on routes that
>   didn't need it, e.g. a feed of bug questions. The access happened
>   after headers had already been sent, meaning the cookie refresh
>   couldn't take place. Subsequent requests now had invalid cookies and a
>   logout was forced.
>
> I apologize and a fix will be pushed shortly.

Comment: Hurray! I look forward to the fix.

Comment: ...But might not even notice it :P