# How can I get support for an untreated bug report/feature request posted on Meta?

Tags: support, meta

I'm facing a problem which already has an open [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) meta discussion (in this case [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166874/getting-logged-out-multiple-times-issue-continues) but the question is in general).

However the existing [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) isn't being treated, if I ask another question it will be closed as duplicate so I want to draw attention to the other question. I voted the question up  over a week ago but it still isn't getting any attention.

Is there a way to get SE's developers attention to an existing question? Also is there a way to know that a specific problem is being treated? (such as an [in-progress](/questions/tagged/in-progress) tag).

Comment: We can't force the team to anything, it's totally up to them. Most we can do is start a bounty, sometimes it draws more attention from devs and sometimes it's not. If it's urgent issue preventing you from using the site you can use the [contact form](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) to contact them directly.

Comment: You should start a bounty first.

Comment: There are already [status-confirmed], [status-planned] or [status-review] tags which to some extent indicate the "in progress" nature of a bug-fix. But that's about it.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby On the main site, I'd say this is appropriate, but on meta, the attention that you need to get can only be addressed by a select few, and meta rep is worthless (on this site) and non-existent on 2.0 sites.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to draw attention to a particular post on any of the Stack Exchange sites - including Meta.SO - is to raise a [bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) against it.

That will add it to the 'Featured' tab of questions and would - in theory - give it more visibility for people to respond to.

However, a bounty does not guarantee that anyone will look at it, respond to it or action it, it just promotes it for a week so it would get more attention.

Now, just because you can't guarantee a dev will look into the issue by raising a bounty it *could* prompt other people to vote it up and comment if they have the same issues themselves. If the same problem exists for numerous users then it's possibly more likely that it'll get looked at as an actual bug. But again, no guarantees.