# Non-HTTPS link in notifications areas on HTTPS SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, ssl

I have noticed that since getting the Firefox add-on `HTTPS Everywhere` that all SE sites have gone HTTPS as they should, however I have also noticed that on the HTTPS versions every site link except for the links in the notifications areas are HTTPS too, so I think that this should change so that on the HTTPS version of the SE sites the links to questions and answers in the notifications areas are HTTPS as well. That is the `INBOX` and `ACHIEVEMENTS` notification areas.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183034/160917.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All links in these areas now go to `https://` endpoints as part of our overall HTTPS migration, enjoy!

Comment: Great! My HTTPS Everywhere add-on still reports there to be non-HTTPS scripts being used on this page in chat which sometimes causes problems because I block them all by default. Will this be also fixed soon?