# I cannot post two questions in a day

Tags: support, new-users, rate-limiting

I asked a question by 9:30 am (IST) and cannot ask another now at 4:00 pm. The error show that we cannot ask two questions in 20 mins. However, the error is incorrect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume this is caused by other accounts (of yours?) [using the same IP address](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/):

> If you’re a new user, with reputation below 100:
>
> 1. You may only post 1 question every 20 minutes
> 2. You may only post 1 answer every 3 minutes
>
> This is tracked at the IP address level, so multiple posts from the same IP, even as different “users”, will still be blocked.

Comment: Good catch, probably company IP and other work mates have accounts as well.

Comment: This makes me wonder if *all* posts from an IP are counted when trying to determine if the low-rep user can post again. Or only posts *from other low-rep users*, @Shadow.

Comment: @Shadow - let's hope so and it's not a case of sockpuppetry.

Comment: I understand. However we have serveral users. Is there any solution that StackOverflow can implement.

Comment: @Chris, just curious: do moderators have tools to find similar accounts based on email address or IP address?

Comment: @Ravi, when you read the linked blog post, then unfortunately I guess there's no other solution than patience, and getting reputation. (But, as for getting reputation: beware that [monitoring is in place](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/).)

Comment: @Arjan - Not directly. We can do certain amount of cross referencing, but only when a user is brought to our attention.

Comment: @Ravi if other people in your own team have separate accounts and none of you is using the account for "personal" use (meaning questions not related to your work projects) consider making one account instead. I doubt StackOverflow will change anything, as it will cause more abuse of the system.

Comment: @Shadow While I'm not personally opposed to it (there are equal risks, in my mind, to the benefits of shared accounts), I will alert you to the presence of [a discussion exactly about shared accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82509/what-is-the-view-on-accounts-shared-by-multiple-users-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: I wonder what will happen the moment we run out of IP4 address space (isn't that mere months away?) and providers start too use NAT to pool their users. I'm using my country's biggest ISP and could find myself sharing an IP address with dozens, if not hundreds of SO users. I suppose fraud detection will run amok...

Comment: I am no expert at all, @sbi, but I'd hope providers would then somehow map the NATted IPv4 to unique IPv6 addresses outside of its own network? (But then: even when that is doable, if the provider is not prepared for IPv6 to start with, then they might not have smart workarounds either...) As for SE: [Would it be possible for Stackoverflow to be accessible over IPv6?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/would-it-be-possible-for-stackoverflow-to-be-accessible-over-ipv6)