# World IPv6 Day?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, ipv6

Following on from whether it would be possible for [Stack Overflow to be available over IPv6](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/would-it-be-possible-for-stackoverflow-to-be-accessible-over-ipv6), will the Stack Exchange network be participating in [World IPv6 day](http://isoc.org/wp/worldipv6day/) 2011 (8 June 2011)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would it be possible for Stackoverflow to be accessible over IPv6?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/would-it-be-possible-for-stackoverflow-to-be-accessible-over-ipv6) - The only difference I can tell is this question has a deadline.  It probably would have been better to add a bounty to the existing IPv6 question.

Comment: And [are YOU ready](http://testipv6.com/), dear reader? And if yes, did you set up your IPv6 [to not to expose too much](http://superuser.com/questions/243669/how-to-avoid-exposing-my-mac-address-when-using-ipv6)?

Comment: Actually no, my ISP sucks. Luckily the HE tunnels are pretty good (http://www.he.net/) (and free) (and don't contain my mac address) and I've been using them for some time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We'll look into doing this next year.

Comment: You know the current price for an IPv4 address [is $11.25, and rising](http://www.hydrapinion.com/index.php/work/2011/03/27/m-soft-confirms-your-ip-address-is-worth)! ;-)

Comment: Fair enough.  Spam and LQQ blocking is probably the biggest problem I can see from the outside.

Comment: Still looking into this next year?

Comment: Beware, this year it's actually [World IPv6 **launch**](http://www.worldipv6launch.org/), 9 days left! ;-)

Comment: @arjan or 372 days left i did say 'next' year

Comment: Ah, you're saying you failed? ;-)

Comment: So, jokes aside, any plans, progress, ...? Or just not a priority?

Comment: Its a pet project of @petergrace no progress this year but it is on our radar

Comment: It has been almost a year since the last update here, have there been any updates?

Comment: @zaphoyd I'd give it 6-8 weeks

Comment: Just 2 more years and you'll be able to do it for IPv6's 20th birthday

Comment: Tomorrow never comes?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma 6-8 years have not passed yet. Give them time. :)

Comment: @ShaWiz 6-8 years have now passed.