# Stack Overflow over IPv6 on World IPv6 Launch Day

Tags: feature-request, ipv6

First of all, I *know* that this question covers a similar ground as [Would it be possible for Stack Overflow to be accessible over IPv6?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/would-it-be-possible-for-stack-overflow-to-be-accessible-over-ipv6) but the topic is one year old and pertaining to the last year's World IPv6 Day.

Today is June 6, 2012, [the World IPv6 **Launch** Day](http://www.worldipv6launch.org/), so I ask whether SE has made any plans to enable IPv6 on their servers in this year. Many large content providers such as Google,  Facebook and perhaps most importantly Akamai have already made the switch so it is possible to access a somewhat large portion of Internet via IPv6 only.

Since IPv4 depletion is becoming more and more a severe issue we can expect that ISPs that won't be able to get new IPv4 allocations will start connecting their clients to IPv6-only connections or resort to CGNs which bring about many other problems such as identification of clients behind those CGNs and performance issues.

I think many users will appreciate IPv6 connectivity to SE and I think it is not a large problem from a technical viewpoint. A reverse IPv6 proxy will probably do just fine for the time being (similar to what Amazon AWS [currently uses](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-elb-ipv6.html) to provide IPv6 connectivity to their clients while they are upgrading the platform to the full-fledged IPv6 connectivity)

**EDIT:** Bump, because it's 2014 and IPv6 is still not there.

Comment: `I think many users will appreciate IPv6 connectivity to SE and I think it is not a large problem from a technical viewpoint.` I think both claims need some citation.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that *many* and *large* are relative terms. What I actually meant is that I thank that many users would appreciate the feature (IPv6 is The Future of the Internet™ afterall) even if they don't have a need for it at the moment. As for the second part, it may have been an overstatement but rudimentary IPv6 support is generally easy to provide. Also, accepted answer on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/would-it-be-possible-for-stack-overflow-to-be-accessible-over-ipv6 states that there are no upstream limitations for SE to adopt IPv6.

Comment: If the OP people are afraid of technical issues why not enable IPv6 only on Server Fault at first. Users of that site should have no problem reporting routing issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [World IPv6 Day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86227/world-ipv6-day)

Comment: Though [I too would like it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/86227/revisions) (though it wouldn't make a difference to me), a dupe is a dupe, no matter how old it is.

Comment: @Arjan Last year was "The world IPv6 day". This year is "The world IPv6 *launch* day".

Comment: Sure, @Alexandre, and last year it was 2011 and this year 2012. No matter what, this very question is answered in the duplicate.

Comment: Is it possible to push a thread with a comment?^^