# IPv6 and the StackExchange network

Tags: feature-request, hosting, ipv6

This morning I'm working in a cafe where bizarrely the WiFi DHCP gave me an IPv6 address (and DNS, etc), but no IPv4.

As such, I can use IPv6-enabled sites such as [google.com](https://www.google.com/), but stack exchange sites appear not to resolve (at least in chrome on OSX).

Can IPv6 be enabled for the stack exchange network?

<sub>(Don't worry, I'm now tethered to my iphone, so I can get my work done.)</sub>

---

#### Update:

Now this has been migrated to meta.SE (where it should be), I see there are several possible duplicates:

- [2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/would-it-be-possible-for-stack-overflow-to-be-accessible-over-ipv6)
- [2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86227/world-ipv6-day)
- [2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134740/stack-overflow-over-ipv6-on-world-ipv6-launch-day)

However, none of these seem to have a conclusive answer - either of:

- "Yes, we will support IPv6 on X date"
- "No, we have no plans to support IPv6".

I know this is now a dup (as it probably should be), but I would love to see a useful answer.

Comment: I would try to get hold of Nick Craver and ask it.

Comment: @Braiam ok - I pinged him in chat.  Out of interest, why the retagging from [tag:feature-request] to [tag:support]?  To me that implies that IPv6 support already exists and I'm just using it wrong - is that the case?

Comment: @ShadowWizard "This question already has an answer here". Where is the answer?

Comment: @2426021684 so you prefer that if we want something to be done, we should ask it 1000 times, leaving all of them open on purpose? And have SE team post the same answer when doing or declining it? Sorry, but I really don't think so. That will be total mess and that's what I fight against. (i.e. doing my best to keep this site organized, with same requests/bugs closed as duplicates.)

Comment: @Braiam agree with the OP, this is not a support question. Any reason for choosing that wrong tag that we might have missed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard a feature request is already a duplicated, and this question reads more like "I think SE supports IPv6 but for some reason is not accessible to me" support question

Comment: @Braiam "but stack exchange sites appear not to resolve", "Can IPv6 be enabled for the stack exchange network". How exactly you reached such a conclusion??