# Stack Exchange and IPv6

Tags: feature-request, ipv6

Well, it has been over 7 years since World IPv6 Launch Day, when [Stack Overflow over IPv6 on World IPv6 Launch Day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134740/369973) was asked (with no answer, yet).

It would seem to be a great shame for a technology company not to be able to support IPv6 in 2019. I am about ready to shut down IPv4 on my network, but I cannot because SE doesn't support IPv6, and I really have not seen an explanation or any plans or timelines when support may be expected. Just about every other site that I regularly use supports IPv6, and I did shut down IPv4 for a while as an experiment, but I needed to enable it for the SE sites.

One suggestion in the comments was to enable it for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), and we now have [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). SE as a company should at least be able to dip its toe into IPv6, or at least explain to its users a broad outline of its plans.

Are there any plans for SE IPv6 support? Is there even a wild guess for the time frame? Do I need abandon SE? Please, someone from SE fill us in on anything related to IPv6.

Comment: It's going to be a long time before all major websites have a fully functioning IPv6 address. While I think IPv6 would be nice for SE, if you plan to go 100% IPv4-free, you need to expect breakage.

Comment: going 100% ipv4 free is... dumb. And I don't use that word lightly. IPv6 support would be shiny, but the usefulness depends on the ISP, and its something you hardly notice unless you're *seriously* lucky or take the effort to set up a tunnel

Comment: @forest: "_It's going to be a long time before all major websites have a fully functioning IPv6 address._" That is simply not true. Almost _all_ the major web sites _are_ fully functional on IPv6, which is why I could disable IPv4, except for SE.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, what is dumb is needing NAPT and breaking the IP paradigm. Also, when looking at my firewall logs, there are several orders of magnitude in difference between the number of IPv4 attacks to IPv6 attacks attempted against my network. Obviously, that will change at some point, but simply losing that traffic would be great.

Comment: @RonMaupin - that simply isn't true. As a backbone, IPv6 is grand, but end to end there are still problems all over. Lots needs fixing before this will be reliable. And there are many more important bugs/features to sort first :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop, I am a network engineer who works with this stuff every day, and IPv6 is fully ready for prime time. It improves IP in multiple ways, and it restores the IP paradigm that NAPT breaks. See the answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/53935/8499) on Network Engineering.

Comment: I live in a modern, first world country with multiple ISPs. *ONE* ISP of about 6-7 has native IPv6  listed as a feature, and such. And I occationally have things on servers breaking. Folks who can knowingly take advantage of ipv6 is a 1% of sorts, and I suspect IPv4 will never 'really' be gone, at least in consumer and internal networks.

Comment: Hey @RonMaupin - That's good for you. I am also a fully qualified network engineer, and I try to break things like IPv6 :-) Guess what, it breaks. It is not yet resilient enough for prime time. I want it to be - as it **should** be much better. Hopefully soon (probably more than 6-8 weeks though...)

Comment: I guess it also depends on your definition of a "major website".  As a quick check, while my ISP supports IPv6 traffic, their own website is IPv4.  As is my cell phone provider's.

Comment: @RoryAlsop  One can easily break IPv4 too.

Comment: Correct - however ISPs round the world understand many (not all) of the failure modes of IPv4 and have resilience in place. IPv6 is still not implemented well enough nor extensively enough.

Comment: @RoryAlsop The only way the ISPs will implement resiliency is if their customers demand it, and the only way that will happen is if we start using it.  If you wait for IPv6 to be perfect, it will simply never happen.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, there are about [80,000 web sites registered with and verified by the IPv6 Forum](https://www.ipv6forum.com/ipv6_enabled/approval_list.php#). Virtually every site I use, except SE, is on the list, and all I have tested with IPv6-only work just fine.

Comment: Relevant: https://ipv6excuses.com/

Comment: @MartinSchröder let's be honest the main excuse is: "we don't want to deal with it, and IPv4 mostly works" it's not true but it's the main excuse.

Comment: @Mgetz, I have posted something similar at the end of my answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/53935/8499).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348224/821436

Comment: I stumbled across this: "_It would be disappointing to discover that a service provider has not yet implemented IPv6 at all. That would be a huge red warning flag that the service provider is **not innovative when it comes to network technology**. If the provider isn’t offering IPv6 services at this stage, **it calls into question its prioritization of innovation and whether it is falling behind the competition in other areas**._"

Answer (score -3):

I'm posting this as an answer because it's too long to fit into a comment.

Actually, I'm shocked that Stack Exchange is still running on IPv4 only.

IPv6-only deployments are already on the rise. I have a list of IPv6-only websites, and that list is only getting longer. Since fall 2023, I keep hearing that several experts say that the tipping point for IPv6 transition has been reached. In January 2024, the [Czech](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Czech#Adjective) government has announced that they will shut down IPv4 on the Czech government networks on 2032-06-06. And I expect others to follow that announcement. IPv6 is the new normal and a must-have that nobody can hide from anymore.

On top of that, there are use cases where users might want to use [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) or [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) from an Internet connection that is not a standard issue network access (e.g., an IPv6-only testing environment or a broken network that needs to be fixed or whatever). I sometimes switch my own network connection to IPv6-only for testing purposes, although recently I actually encountered a buggy dual-stacked mail-order company that would only take my order with IPv4 disabled on the client side! So I had to go IPv6-only temporarily just to place an order. With this thought in mind, I think Stack Exchange's role in the IPv6 transition should be the early adopter, not the laggard.

That said, I think it's overdue that SE does its homework to get IPv6 to work. It's 2024.

Comment: The report of IPv4's demise was an exaggeration. And was for a very long time. Are you sure? Gibson has talked about it for as long [the show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Now) has existed.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum: Although much of what Gibson says is true, he has a tendency to exaggerate his technical opinions and state them as facts. For something as subjective as whether or not IPv6 is worth it, I wouldn't take him seriously.