# Problems with CDN DNS

Tags: bug, status-completed, cdn, ipv6

I've been having trouble getting to `cdn.sstatic.net` all day. It's been crippling not to be able to play Stack Exchange!

Chrome's resource panel was showing 'host not found' for `cdn.sstatic.net`.

I think I've tracked it down to this:

I have IPv6 connectivity and my machine is querying for `AAAA` records first. Here's how it goes:

```
[michael@challenger:~]$ host -t ANY cdn.sstatic.net 8.8.8.8
cdn.sstatic.net is an alias for sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net.
```

OK, a CNAME, let's follow that:

```
[michael@challenger:~]$ host -t AAAA sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net 8.8.8.8
Host sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Whoah! That's not good. NXDOMAIN means that domain doesn't exist. That's not right. Let's try a different domain to see what *should* be happening:

```
[michael@challenger:~]$ host -t AAAA serverfault.com 8.8.8.8
serverfault.com has no AAAA record
```

Not sure what *exactly* is going on here, but someone needs to fix something.

Could be lame referrals: http://dns.squish.net/traverses/90336bfcff65c12ee97d57f05e0ce2df/detail

Comment: Last I checked, StackExchange doesn't support IPV6, so they wouldn't have an AAAA record. [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86227/world-ipv6-day), for instance, is still status-deferred. Also, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/would-it-be-possible-for-stack-overflow-to-be-accessible-over-ipv6).

Comment: The problem isn't that no AAAA records exist. The problem is that the CDN DNS servers are returning NXDOMAIN ("the domain doesn't exist"), not "no records of that type".

Comment: FWIW, I had a lot of trouble getting files to download from the CDN this morning, but I haven't had any troubles since I got them downloaded.

Comment: The same thing happens with a type A query, too. One of CloudFlare's DNS servers is on the fritz. The thing is, IPv4-only people won't notice because the other DNS servers are returning responses. But people with IPv6 (like myself) will have more trouble because of the bad response for the AAAA query.

Comment: Absolutely a DNS problem.

Comment: We have been making some changes in this area; I've flagged this up to the perpetr... er, I mean: developer involved

Comment: lol `It's been crippling not to be able to play Stack Exchange!`

Comment: I hope you meant **flogged** @Marc

Comment: @Pekka웃 working remotely, I can only flag, not flog; I need to save up the flogging until I next see the team.

Comment: @MarcGravell Developer? It's an ops problem! :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton - never heard of [devops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps)?

Comment: CloudFlare is looking into the issue...unfortunately the lack of IPv6 on many of our teams' ISPs make it difficult to repro and debug.

Comment: `The only winning move is not to`...aww, yeah, okay.

Comment: @Oded Heard of devops. Never seen it done right.

Comment: @NickCraver: he.net and sixxs.net both offer free IPv6 tunnels,  simple to setup and run.

Comment: @MichaelHampton We do devops pretty well here, if I don't say so myself.  Our devs are very invested in our operations.

Comment: @MikeyB We are continuing to follow up on this situation.

Comment: @MikeyB We've got what we perceive to be a fix in place.  Can you confirm?

Comment: @StevenMurawski Yes, CloudFlare DNS is working for me now.

Comment: OK, well, it _was_ working. Now cdn.sstatic.net is nothing but 2(SERVFAIL).

Comment: @StevenMurawski It's working for me! Hey! IPv6 addresses!

Comment: Mikey, do you think it's a problem that [your DNS debug link](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/90336bfcff65c12ee97d57f05e0ce2df/detail) still shows "lame referrals" today, while [a new test](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/16b85c8d9e5ed855572a0b0138c7f0da/detail) uses a different root server, and seems to indicate all is fine? I do see a date of June 1st in your test, but I don't know how much (outdated) data is used when I click that link and see the results being built-up again. (And I don't know if those "lame referrals" might make some DNS servers give up?)

Comment: And just in case things change: right now your link shows `k.root-servers.net, 193.0.14.129 (1 roots returned)` ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/goCug.png)), mine `d.root-servers.net, 199.7.91.13 (1 roots returned)` ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AvMs6.png)).

Comment: (@Steven, if you know a lot about DNS, then see my comments above, just because every now and then some are reporting *"Oops! Google Chrome could not find cdn.sstatic.net"*, though I don't know if they are on IPv6... `;-)`)

Comment: Just for future reference: today [I hit c.root-servers.net](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/a1c62065ed87d86910cd34d6165ca260/detail) using that debug tool. All fine. The [link](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/90336bfcff65c12ee97d57f05e0ce2df/detail) from the question still shows it's using k.root-servers.net, and still has those "lame referrals". My earlier August 4th [test](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/16b85c8d9e5ed855572a0b0138c7f0da/detail) still uses d.root-servers.net, and is still fine. It seems that the debug links might always use the same root server, no matter when they are used.

Comment: Again just for future reference: today [I got m.root-servers.net](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/f9f616d4b66df306e9ffba19677a771d/detail) and all is fine. No changes for the earlier links. (Some people are still [having issues without IPv6 though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190958/static-content-cdn-is-unreliable-for-me-often-showing-hostname-could-not-be-fo?noredirect=1#comment610260_190958) which earlier seemed to be related to HTTPS.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually an edge case we hit with our CDN.  We've enabled IPv6 support on our CDN, which should resolve the issue for the time being.  We'll continue to monitor the resolution of these DNS entries for both A and AAAA queries.

Comment: Just in case it helps: I'm on IPv6 too, and I did NOT get any problems, from Amsterdam.

Comment: Learned something new today, but I don't know if it means anything ;-) When I run `host -t ANY ...` with my own provider, I *only* get IPv6 addresses (if available). Like `host -t ANY sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net` only gets me IPv6 addresses. But with Google, I get both IPv4 and IPv6, like `host -t ANY sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net 8.8.8.8`. The Google output matches the output of NOT using `-t ANY` with my own provider. Again: it might not mean anything, but who knows ;-) (So far, I was always using `-t AAAA` to force seeing IPv6.)

Comment: And though I have no problems, `nslookup -type=AAAA cdn.sstatic.net` on my Mac shows `Non-authoritative answer [...]` just fine, but also an EMPTY line after `Authoritative answers can be found from:`. Same when using Google, `nslookup -type=AAAA cdn.sstatic.net 8.8.8.8` (Again, no idea if it implies *anything*. Using `host -t AAAA cdn.sstatic.net` does not give me any clue about authoritativeness at all.)

Comment: I am currently having this problem. I am having to disable IPv6 on my network adapter in order to access stack overflow.

Comment: Test test test test