# CSS CDN is unavailable - Why not be more helpful and provide an alternate source?

Tags: bug, cdn

Your CDN that serves your CSS was unavailable for a period today for my region.  Please help users that might be experiencing that issue and provide an alternate source when that is unavailable, possibly serve the one that is on your own servers.

This can be localized to a region and not affect everyone at the same time.  [See this article by Hanselman that explains why it occurs and what you can do to fix it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx).

I don't agree that this is a duplicate of the other question for two reasons:

- This is not related to IPV6.
- This question provides a call to action to provide an alternate CSS when the CDN is unavailable to a user.

Comment: CDN works for me, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Ugly html only on the main stackoverflow page.This webpage is not available
The webpage at http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=c9b143e6d693 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Comment: @user Any firewalls?

Comment: No, and thanks for the downvotes instead of answering the question.  CSS on meta works fine.

Comment: It's back now but bad experience while it was down for me, thus the suggestion to add an alternate, which was downvoted.

Comment: This might have been a localized problem, not necessarily to do with Stack Exchange at all. Also, I'm not sure there is a way to provide a fallback for failing CSS files at all....

Comment: Are you using IPV6? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182594/problems-with-cdn-dns

Comment: Not using IPV6. Also this can be very localized issue to a region. See this article by Hanselman both on why this happens and what you should do to fix it: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx

Comment: @Pekka, yes there is a way and have added a resource that explains.

Comment: @Oded I had a few CDN CSS problems yesterday from HQ as well, but only on some sites. It was intermittent enough that I didn't think much of it at the time.

Comment: @AnnaLear - We just switched over yesterday, so a few hiccups are to be expected. As tunkey commented, the problems with DNS can be highly localized - not sure there is much we can do about _that_.

Comment: @Oded Yep, I know. Just throwing another data point into the ring in case it does ever become helpful.

Comment: Depending where you are, the SERVFAIL DNS issue with CloudFlare may cause trouble even on IPv4-only connections. So it's not limited to IPv6, though it's more severe if you have IPv6. I've marked this as a dupe since they are exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Oded, please check the link in the post for a suggestion on how to get around the issue by providing an alternate location.

Comment: @turnkey that doesn't work for CSS.  The proper fix here is to have the CDN working properly, not providing multiple locations that may or may not strain us for bandwidth.  If something's down for many people we'll change a setting and give *everyone* a different URL to fetch from.

Comment: Ouch you're right his article didn't address the CSS part. This question on SO does give an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383163/how-to-fallback-to-local-stylesheet-not-script-if-cdn-fails