# Cannot load stylesheets from cdn.sstatic.net

Tags: support, cdn

Within the last few days the stylesheet for Stack Overflow hasn't been loading. Was it recently switched to the CDN? Or has it been there for awhile?

If it's been there for awhile, I'm not sure what has changed. I haven't messed with any of my internet settings or anything. I am not behind any proxies and disabling my firewall doesn't help either.

I am having trouble with anything on my home internet, this isn't a company internet or anything that has a bunch of filters setup. I get [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIjrc.png) when I visit http://cdn.sstatic.net in my browser:

> **Sorry we are experiencing technical issues.**
>
> Please click here to refresh this page.
>
> If the problem persists, please call 1-800-COMCAST (1-800-266-2278) and reference AUPM Service Notice.

So I am thinking it has something to do with my ISP. I am switching from Comcast in approximately two weeks. But is there a workaround for this problem in the mean time?

Comment: Pretty sure it's Comcast, they hijack traffic and inject their own crud into your pages, etc.  See, also http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ .  I'd switch now, if you can.  Use Sonic.net if it's in your area. They're tops in service and they don't throttle, hijack, spy, or honor unlawful government "requests".  See, also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100103 .

Comment: Unfortunately my area only offers Comcast/U-Verse. So I'm going to switch to U-Verse and see how it goes ... the weird thing I didn't have a problem until yesterday.

Comment: So, what are the results from the link Awesome posted?

Comment: And is your *"I am having trouble with anything on my home internet"* indicating that a lot of other things fail too? (And yes, the CSS and JavaScript have been loaded from the CDN for a long time now.)

Comment: A quick search for "AUPM Notice" gets me [the Comcast Acceptable Use Policy](http://www.comcast.com/Corporate/Customers/Policies/HighSpeedInternetAUP.html). Maybe it's not even Comcast's fault? I'd say: give them a call.

Comment: @Arjan: It seems SE [changed their CDN provider](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182632/css-cdn-is-unavailable-why-not-be-more-helpful-and-provide-an-alternate-source#comment556603_182632) yesterday, hence all the new posts about CDN problems.

Comment: By "I am having trouble with anything on my internet" I meant all of the devices on my home internet cannot see the stylesheet. Nothing else is having a problem... sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

That is your Internet Service Provider causing those issues, not Stack Overflow. Most likely latency or packet loss...