# SO and SU all.css not loading

Tags: bug, page-load

For some reason, all.css and stub.js are not loading when I try and access both Stackoverflow and SuperUser from my home network (both on Firefox and Chrome).

This issue is fixed when I use a proxy.

Currently, the pages look like this for me:

[image]

Is this happening for other people as well? I have been unable to load the pages normally for about an hour.

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102257/187824

Comment: Given the recent CDN changes, those aren't necessarily duplicates.

Comment: It's probably related to [the CloudFlare DNS failure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182594/189912).