# Bypassing the rate limiting from multiple users at the same IP address

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting, ip-address

At school I am constantly getting the "You can only post once every 90 minutes" message, even if I have never posted before.
After a bit of research I found out that this was not actually my account, but my IP, which is shared with other users at my school.
Is there any way to get past this without just using my phone's hotspot to post?

Answer (score 16):

According to the [rate-limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/245360) the rate limit is not imposed if you have more than 125 reputation.

So the best thing for you to do is contribute positively to the community, either by suggesting good edits or posting answers.

Answer (score 8):

Not currently, but it's something we're reviewing.

We now have offices with *thousands* of employees using Stack Overflow which wasn't the case when we put those limits into place. While it's still fairly uncommon, it's getting to the point where the support cases it creates can be sometimes overwhelming for us (and equally frustrating for them).

I can't give too much detail, but I'm looking into a way where we can do it based on past quality from new users sharing an IP address (and neighboring IPs), which is something that we've been building in cache but haven't put to too much practical use yet.

This is in line with some improvements we're looking at for the spam system. I don't yet have an ETA, but if I had to guess it would be the first half of next year.

Comment: ["Next year", more than 5 years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86234/152859). Hmm...